# Project setup in IntelliJ IDEA for three java modules, one used as a module for the other two

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, project

I am trying to setup a multi module java project based on Gradle in IntelliJ IDEA:

Three modules (I guess), one meant as a library that is used by the two other modules. I fail to get the project configuration right, maybe someone can give me a hint here:

Depending on how I reference the library module from the other modules I manage to get the syntax highlighting find the referenced (imported) classes, but that does not work for the compiler, that one still complains about classes not found. 
So I guess my question is: what is the right approach to reference the classes in the library module from the other two modules in the project structure setup?

This is the setup:

```
/..../pow/library
         /spring
         /droid
```

`setup.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'pow'

include 'library'
include 'spring'
include 'droid'
```

`build.gradle`:

```
group 'org.rustygnome.pow'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

allprojects {
    group 'org.rustygnome.pow'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
}
```

`library/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

//sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.json:json:20171018'
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    compile files('/home/arkascha/Projects/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

`spring/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'org.rustygnome.pow.spring.Application'
    baseName = 'pow-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Using that setup I want to assemble the `spring` module. In that modules sources I reference a class from the `library` module:

`Application.java`:

```
package org.rustygnome.pow.spring;

import org.rustygnome.pow.lib.config.Config;
// other imports

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements ApplicationRunner {

    static ApplicationContext appContext;
    static ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    Config config; // this one references 
// further stuff
```

The `library` module is built, no issues there.

But when I try to build the `spring module` I get:

> 11:14:38 AM: Executing task 'build'...
>
> /data/Projects/pow/spring/src/main/java/org/rustygnome/pow/spring/Application.java:3:
>
> error: package org.rustygnome.pow.lib.config does not exist
>
> import org.rustygnome.pow.lib.config.Config;
>
> // ... further issues...

Answer (score 1):

[Composite builds](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/webinar-recording-composite-builds-with-gradle/) seems to be what you need.

[Gradle reference for the composite builds feature](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html).

You can also use [Multi-Projects](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/).

Comment: Hm, sounds god, but I fail to succeed. Seems to come out the same, whether I enter the includeBuild manually in gradle or use the IDEA project structure dialog. Syntax highlighting is satisfied, I can import classes from the library module, but the compiler still complains that the libraries packages don't exist.

Comment: @arkascha IntelliJ IDEA synchronization is one way only, all the changes should be performed in the gradle build files, then refreshed in the IDE. If the command line Gradle build works, it should also work in the IDE.

Comment: I added a `includeBuild 'library' in the settings.gradle file and synchronized the gradle dock in IDEA, no change. I need to add the library folder/module in the project structure dialog, otherwise it is not found at all. But as said that des not help the compiler.

Comment: @arkascha please share [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sure, you are right. I put additional details into the question, I think those are the relevant parts.

Comment: @arkascha a link to the zipped project directory would be much more useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172805/discussion-between-arkascha-and-crazycoder).

Comment: Still no success... Did you manage to take a short look at that archive?

Comment: Can you point where did you specify the dependencies between the modules in the build.gradle files?

Comment: Actually tried all sorts of things, took them out again. I expected to be able to do that using the IDEs "project structure" dialog but failed. I did not check how that changed the various gradle files, though I did observe changes, the sync canot be strictly into one direction. I also tried adding a `includeBuild 'library'` in the central `settings.gradle` or compile dependencies in spring's `build.gradle`. I am afraid I cannot really pinpoint all attempts, I did not expect that to be so difficult to find out.